# Raspberry pi music player linked to internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm thinking of using my old raspberry pi as a music player which would allow devices to access it and play music over LAN. I am wanting to do something with tomahawk and beets to access the media through the net. Is there any way I can stream audio from the Internet and not from already saved local audio files? Like add the meta data where it will support most links from websites such as youtube, spotify, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way how to do it is using implementation of KODI (https://kodi.tv/). You can access it also over internet, but you have to manage a lot of other things, like accessing pi over internet (for example port forwarding, public IP etc.) or security (ssh port scanning, bruteforce attacks)...

I recomend you to start with basic instalation of KODI a then you can learn some other things like ssh your pi over in internet, etc.